# Compressing content from a reverse proxy using mod_filter?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-filter

I am trying to compress certain content from a reverse proxy by using mod_filter. The only way to know the mime type of the content is by inspecting the Content-Type header from the back end. The request URI is not a useful selector here because the system (Plone) keeps track of mime types without regard to filename or location.

This configuration seems to do basically what I want, compressing everything and then decompressing it again if it is an application, but that seems like a waste.

I would rather be able to AND and OR multiple conditions to decide whether to apply compression, duplicating the SetOutputFilter DEFLATE setup from the docs that everyone uses in a way that works with ProxyPass.

Is it possible to `AND` multiple conditions for mod_filter's FilterProvider?

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
<Location />
    FilterDeclare gzip CONTENT_SET
    FilterDeclare gzipinflate CONTENT_SET
    FilterDeclare gzipinflate2 CONTENT_SET
    FilterProvider gzip deflate req=Accept-Encoding $gzip
    FilterProvider gzipinflate inflate resp=Content-Type $application/
    FilterChain +gzip +gzipinflate
</Location>
```